# Java GridLayout how to dynamically change grid layout

Tags: java, dynamic, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to create a character sheet program that arranges 3 panels based on how wide the frame is. If the frame is not very wide, I want the panels to be arranged vertically, but if the user chooses to make the frame wider, I would like to arrange the panels horizontally.

I also have a scrollPanel that the 3 panels are arranged on, so the scrollPanel is being added to a scrollPane.

I have seen posts that say that an eventlistener would work, however most of these are for buttons, and I need the Frame size to pass a certain threshold before the layout changes. I seen other posts that recommend html which I don't see as necessary right now.

[image]

So in this picture the 3 panels are arranged vertically, and are able to be scrolled through.

```
    scrollPanel.add(leftPanel); //this is the yellow panel that is being added
    scrollPanel.add(centerPanel); //this one is farther down
    scrollPanel.add(rightPanel); //even farther down
    scrollPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    scrollPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1)); //so here I would like to have an if statement or event swap the 0 and the 1.
```

Summary:

- Can I change a GridLayout dynamically based on the size of a Frame?
- How do I monitor for a Frame size change? event? if statement?
- Can I do the same with a ScrollPane with setting the horizontal and vertical scroll bars to never appear based on if the panels are vertical or horizontal?

Comment: this is 3-in-one; yes you can change anything dynamically; did you try??

Comment: Do I use an if statement to change the gridLayout? Do change the existing one or do I need to create a new one?

Comment: yes you can use an if statement - is this your code? did you create this code? - you can start a new GridLayout or set the rows/columns see the doc for GridLayout -

Comment: Yes I created it. I currently have the gridLayout set to vertical so it is organizing the panels vertically (you just can't see the other 2 because it is in a scroll pane). I was not sure how to change it so the gridLayout organizes them horizontally or what the best method was for it. So I can basically say if frame is wider than this width, change the layout? Then I remove the current layout and replace it with a different one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the GridLayout as follows:

```
gr.setRows(newR);
gr.setColumns(newC);
myFrame.validate();
```

where gr is the layout you created somewhere and newR/newC are the new numbers of rows/columns.

Or you can say

```
gr=new GridLayout(newR, newC);
myFrame.setLayout(gr);
```

Then

```
if(myFrame.getWidth()>thershold) {

.. do the above

}
```

Comment: When I run these two lines: `gr=new GridLayout(newR, newC);` `myFrame.setLayout(gr);` will that redraw all the elements I have in my `GridLayout` to fit the `newR, newC`?